# How to target soap api requests to a specific business unit

Tags: marketing-cloud

If we use the same username and password for a single account and there are multiple business units how would we target a specific business unit?

For example, posting to a publication list via the c# api only seems to query one business unit. And if the list Id exist in another business unit it says the list does not exist

Answer (score 2):

Okay, I'm new to this.... so I'm happy to be corrected.

If you don't specify the client - it will use the top level business unit... which I suspect is what you are getting.

To access all lists for parent and sub-accounts you need to specify.....

```
    RetrieveRequest MyRequest = new RetrieveRequest();
    MyRequest.ObjectType = "List";
    MyRequest.Properties = new string[] { "ID", "Description", "ListName", "Client.ID"};
    MyRequest.QueryAllAccounts = true;
    MyRequest.QueryAllAccountsSpecified = true; //scans all business units
    MyRequest.Filter = sfp;
```

to search a specific account you need to set the Client attribute....

eg Client.ID = business unit id

Comment: Client ID is needed when working in an ENT 2.0 account and you want to point to a specific Business Unit.  Otherwise, it will look only at your API User's Default Business Unit that you have defined in the UI.

Documentation found here:  https://help.exacttarget.com/en-US/technical_library/web_service_guide/technical_articles/using_clientid_in_your_soap_api_code/